# NginxとApacheの併用は可能？

Tags: nginx, apache

下記ページを参考にしてみたいのですが、Nginxについて教えてください。

CentOS6の環境で、apache2 × nginxな環境を作る
http://qiita.com/monhan/items/013f1a4c1d7f26d0b755

環境(現状)

- CentOS6
- VPS
- バーチャルドメインでApacheのみ使用

質問

- プロキシサーバとして使用したいのですが、リバースプロキシとは違うのでしょうか？
- プロキシサーバとして使用する場合はNginxだけ使用？
- リバースプロキシとして使用する場合はApache＋Nginxを使用？
- なるべく既存設定を変更したくないのですが、nginxは80番ポートを使用する決まりなのでしょうか？
- iptablesの新規追加だけではなく、既存変更が必要？
- そもそも、バーチャルドメインでApacheへアクセスしている状態のまま、さらに指定ドメインをNginxへ(URLでポート番号指定することなく)アクセスさせることは可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ApacheもNginxもHTTP(コンテンツ)サーバであり、プロキシサーバとしても使用することもできます。

リバースプロキシ/フォワードプロキシというのはプロキシサーバによって実現される通信形態のことを言っています。

どちらも一般的な範囲では同じことができますので、一つで両方をやらせたり、併用することもできます。ただし、同一IPアドレス同一ポートにbindできるのは一つのサービスですので、併用する場合はbindするIPアドレスかポートかその両方をどちらかが変更する必要があります。

iptablesの変更が必要かどうかは今の環境とやりたいこと次第です。

> そもそも、バーチャルドメインでApacheへアクセスしている状態のまま、さらに指定ドメインをNginxへ(URLでポート番号指定することなく)アクセスさせることは可能なのでしょうか？

- 複数のIPアドレスを持てるならApacheとNginxでそれぞれのIPアドレスにbindするよう設定する
- 単一IPアドレスで実現したいのであれば、「指定ドメイン」について既存のApacheでvirtualhostを設定したうえリバースプロキシとして動作させ、裏のNginxに転送する

でしょうか。